# how to read xml and bind to dataset in c#

Tags: c#

[image]Actually i have some problem while accessing the xml Nodes i want to find Child Nodes from Root Node Following mine Code

```
  string myXmlString = string.Empty;
                WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

                string Xml = doc.DocumentElement.InnerXml;

                XmlNodeList xnList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Item");


                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("ASIN", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("SalesRank", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("ListPrice", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("AvailabilityType", typeof(string));

                foreach (XmlNode node in xnList)
                {

                    DataRow dtrow = dt.NewRow();
                    dtrow["ASIN"] = node["ASIN"].InnerText;


                    XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("SalesRank");
                    foreach (XmlNode salesNode in elemList)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
                        {
                            dtrow["SalesRank"] = elemList[i].InnerXml;
                        }
                    }

                    XmlNodeList ListPrice = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ListPrice");
                    foreach (XmlNode salesNode in ListPrice)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < ListPrice.Count; i++)
                        {
                            dtrow["ListPrice"] = ListPrice[i].InnerText;
                        }
                    }



                    XmlNodeList AvailbleAttr = doc.GetElementsByTagName("AvailabilityType");
                    foreach (XmlNode AvlNode in AvailbleAttr)
                    {
                        if (AvlNode.Name == "AvailabilityType")
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < AvailbleAttr.Count; i++)
                            {
                                dtrow["AvailabilityType"] = AvailbleAttr[i].InnerText;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(dtrow);
                }
```

This is Above code Actually my    dt.Rows.Add(dtrow); Filled Same values in SalesRank ,ListPrice & AvailabilityType Attribute

So how can I resolve this Problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need of for loop inside the foreach. if you eliminate the for loop and write the statement you write inside the for loop directly in foreach loop by modifying it as follows then you will get the correct result.

dtrow["colname"]=salesnode.InnerXml

otherwise remove the foreach loop and for loop will do what exactly you want.

Comment: as you said i removed Foreach and Write code in ForLoop but in that case all data comes into dt and Filled all xml ,  but i want specific tag.

Comment: if you are removing the foreach loop then don't modify the statement in for loop. if it is the same statement you will not get entire xml and otherwise you might get entire xml. yourself just think the logic you have written. with foreach loop you are accessing one by one element from elemlist in the first loop and inside that loop again accessing one by one element from elemlist based on index.

Comment: Dear, If you can provide sample XML file which you are using, it would be great help, and We can provide exact solutions

Comment: @Anand is the code works? if it works please mention that you got answer  and also specify the solution you followed if it is different from the answers given here. Thank you.

Comment: Yes it work Finally but i used different kind of logic for this issue i will share.

Answer (score 0):

Following my is code that  has solved my problem:

```c#
  private void GetProductDetails()
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("C:\\Users\\ANDY\\Desktop\\XML Data\\Demo.xml");


            XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/users");



            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(string));

            dt.Columns.Add("ADD1", typeof(string));

            //dt.Columns.Add("DEPT", typeof(string)); 



            foreach (XmlNode NodeXml in node)
            {


                DataRow dtrow = dt.NewRow();

                //dtrow["Name"] = NodeXml["Name"].InnerText;

                XmlElement companyElement = (XmlElement)NodeXml;

                dtrow["Name"] = companyElement.GetElementsByTagName("Name")[0].InnerText;
                dtrow["ID"] = companyElement.GetElementsByTagName("ID")[0].InnerText;
                dtrow["FirstName"] = companyElement.GetElementsByTagName("FirstName")[0].InnerText;
                dtrow["LastName"] = companyElement.GetElementsByTagName("LastName")[0].InnerText;
                dtrow["ADD1"] = companyElement.GetElementsByTagName("ADD1")[0].InnerText;
                //xmlCompanyID = companyElement.Attributes["ID"].InnerText;




                //this is ANother Method you can bind ADDR.USING Child Method

                //XmlNode AddrNode = node.SelectSingleNode("/users/DEPT/LOCATION");


                //for (int i = 0; i < AddrNode.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
                //{

                //    if (AddrNode.ChildNodes[i].Name == "ADD1")
                //    {
                //        dtrow["ADD1"] = AddrNode["ADD1"].InnerText;
                //    }
                //}


                  dt.Rows.Add(dtrow);
            }


            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                RepDetails.DataSource = dt;
                RepDetails.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                RepDetails.DataSource = "";
                RepDetails.DataBind();
            }

        }
```